# Задача по информатике на Pascal

Tags: pascal

Ввести два числа с клавиатуры, сравнить целую часть от деления большего числа на меньшее и остаток от деления большего числа на меньшее, и на печать вывести большее число (остаток от деления или целую часть).

**UPD:**

Код Олеси Ромашкиной!!!

Решается как-то так:

```
program Hello;
var
N1, N2 : int64; //определяем два вещественных числа для ввода
comp1 : real;   // результат сравнение целой части от деления большего числа на меньшее
comp2 : real;   // результат сравнение остатка от деления большего числа на меньшее

begin
//  вводим два числа
ReadLn (N1);
ReadLn (N2);
if N1 > N2 then comp1 := trunc (N1/N2) else comp1 := trunc (N2/N1); // вычисляем целую часть от деления большего числа на меньшее
if N1 > N2 then comp2 := N1 mod N2 else comp2 := N2 mod N1; // вычисляем остаток от деления большего числа на меньшее


if comp1 > comp2 then WriteLn (comp1 : 2 : 0) else WriteLn (comp2 : 2 : 0); // определяем какое из получившихся чисел больше и печатаем его
end.
```

Comment: Мне вывело 18, верно?

Comment: Покажите ваш код, как вы пытались писать код?

Comment: @Михаил Камахин, нет, сначала вы покажите :)

Comment: `Comp1 : 2 : 0` что это такое? Вы объявили перменyю comp1, но Comp1 я не видел. И что значит два двоеточия?

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, из справки: a write parameter has the form: OutExpr [: MinWidth [: DecPlaces ] ]. MinWidth - ширина вывода, если текст имеет меньше символов, то он дополняется пробелами слева. DecPlaces - количество десятичных знаков после запятой, при выводе вещественных чисел.

Comment: @Alekcvp я когда в школе был и на паскале писал, как-то обходился остатком от деления, простым % и простым делением /, которое, вроде, целочисленное в паскале

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, вы спросили, я ответил. И да, деление в паскале вещественное, целочисленное - div.